# ZKSforce detail documentation

Tags: ios, salesforce

Is there any documentation available for ZKSforce library which provides effective usage and parsing data through it's object.

Answer (score 0):

There's the [readme](https://github.com/superfell/zkSforce/blob/master/README.md), the comments in [ZKSforceClient.h](https://github.com/superfell/zkSforce/blob/master/zkSforce/zkSforceClient.h) and the [sample code](https://github.com/superfell/zkSforce/tree/master/samples). The docs assume you are already familar with the [Salesforce SOAP API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api250/index.htm), if you're not, checkout the docs for that first.